# How to pass intput to a .exe file using a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, exe

I have a .exe file(let's say abc.exe)that asks for password(let's say it is "pwd") twice when I run it. I want to automate the task by using a batch script. I understood that i can't just give

```
 echo pwd & echo pwd & abc.exe
```

I have a few of questions
1)Is writing a batch script, the best way to automate the process?
2)If so, should my executable abc.exe allow passing parameters to it?

Because I've tried the below piece of code but it doesn't work

```
@echo off
set password="pwd"
abc.exe %password% %password%
```

I still have to give the password 2 times for the executable to work

Answer (score 0):

Using your script, `%password%` results to `"pwd"`. To force it to result in `pwd`, use next `set` command syntax rather:

```
@echo off
set "password=pwd"
abc.exe %password% %password%
```

If your `abc.exe` application does not accept arguments, try [piping](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) with `<tab>` delimiter amidst that two `%password%` occurences (I can't type a `<tab>` character here correctly):

```
echo(%password% %password%|abc.exe
```

Explanation: Double quotes in `set "variable=value"` make sure neither leading nor trailing spaces in both variable *name* and *value* (also note no spaces around `=` as well).

**Edit**: As your `abc.exe` application evidently does not accept either command line arguments or data file for loading password, here is a workaround using windows clipboard: [clip](http://ss64.com/nt/clip.html).

Instead of typing the password twice manually, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> could suffice. On the other hand, your windows clipboard will be overwritten and still contains you password...

```
@echo off
set "password=pwd"
rem with <tab> delimiter amidst that two %password% occurences in next line
echo(%password% %password%|clip
abc.exe
```

Comment: Hi Josef, thanks for the response but it still doesn't work. I still have to give the password twice manually